# Wildcard (?) htaccess redirect to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the following urls to homepage via htaccess. Please let me know if it is possible.

I want all the URLs `https://www.domain.com/?id=*` redirected to homepage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, i got the solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```